# Cannot replace text in dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas

See code. Both "data" and "names" are panda dataFrames. "Names" holds the names for the columns. It is both strings and years as numbers (example '2020new' and '2020'). When I inspect it it looks fine. But when I run the first line (apply it to the columns of "data") it adds '.0' to all fields from name that could be considered pure numbers (so '2020new' remain unchanged but it turns '2020' into '2020.0').

```
data.columns = names
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('.0', '')
```

Can I avoid this adding of "decimals"? It messes up matching for the correct year later in the code. The second line, i thought would solve this but the "replace" actually changes all the "pure numbers" to NaN (not a number). What gives?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: may be the column is a float?

Comment: Try changing `names` into a `list` and then, assign it to `data.columns`.

Comment: I used to change it to a list first, but this makes the dataframe multi-indexed for some reason which I cannot use. Cant I just get rid of the added '.0' for the column names without making it a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename columns of a pandas `DataFrame` using the `DataFrame.rename()` method.

Here is an example how to rename your columns for a dummy DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 1, 2, 3]})

df.rename(columns={"A": "B"})   # Rename your column "A" to "B"
```

or if you want to use variable formatting:

```
c = "C"
df.rename(columns={"A": "{}".format(c)})
```

Remember to reassign your `df` or use `inplace=True` in necessary when using this method.

```
# reassign df
df = df.rename(columns={"A": "{}".format(c)})

# OR use the inplace parameter
df.rename(columns={"A": "{}".format(c)}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: How does this help my question? I dont want to rename the entire thing, i just need the added '.0' ending to go away so I keep my original names. There is many names, I cant just hard-code each possible A and what it's corresponding string B should be.

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example of your original DataFrame and the DataFrame after transformation that includes the issue?

Comment: As I said the original has names like '2020new' and '2020'. The ones that are pure numbers (no letters) are interpreted as numbers and the decimal ending '.0' is added to those (so '2020new' isnt changed but '2020' is changed to '2020.0'.  

I tried this line but it doesnt remove the added decimal in the new column-names (the '.0' ending remains) data.rename(columns={'.0': ''}, inplace=True)

Comment: What are the datatypes of these colum names? All strings? Then you could use the `split()` method. I.e: `str = "2020.0";  str.split('.')[0]` to remove the '.0'. if the names are floats you can use the `int()` function to remove the decimals. Then using a `for` loop to perform the action for every name in your list.

Comment: This works: data.columns.values[7] = int(data.columns.values[7]). BUT i cannot loop through them all since this line crashes the program if it's not a '.0' entry (a string with letters). Can i test each one in the loop before running this line? (i dont know beforehand which columns will be having a .0 ending or not). Still dont understant why the replace line "data.rename(columns={'.0': ''}, inplace=True)" does nothing. Because of datatypes? The ones that get added .0 ending are of type 'numpy.float64'. The ones that get no added .0 is of type 'str'

Answer (score 0):

This works (finally). There was "float NaN" which was hard to deal with (you have to find the specific type of NaN it is since there are several types... stupid. So by casting it to int I get rid of the added ".0" which I don't know why it added in the first place, and then cast to string (needed for easier comparison later on). Sorry for ugly c-style loop. I wanted to be sure what was happening.

```
 i = int(0)
    for column in data:
        if isinstance(column, float):
            if not numpy.isnan(column):
                data.columns.values[i] = str(int(data.columns.values[i]))    
        i = i + 1
```

I employed 8 different people cunning in python to solve this. All their ideas proposed failed to fix this simple problem except this last one. That's not a good grade for python as a language...